# Realm class is not part of the schema object Android

Tags: java, android, realm

I have run into this error everytime I make "Clean and rerun app" in Android Studio.

Even though I have the proxy classes, I still have an "Order is no part of the schema object"

I have tried:

1.Clean and rebuild project.
2.Deleted generated build files manually.
3.Uninstall app before deploying.
4.I have realm in my project gradle and app gradle. (version 1.1.0)
5.I have tried with Order extending RealmObject and implementing RealmModel.
6.RealmConfiguration has deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded.

The only solution I had, was renaming each file but it is really harsh to do it each time I do a clean and re run.

```
        RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .name("myRealmFile")
            .build();

        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);            

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        RealmResults<Order> orders = realm.where(Order.class).equalTo("finished", false).findAll();

        mHasActiveOrder = orders != null && orders.isValid() && orders.size() > 0;

        realm.close();
```

Comment: Show the code of the class that's causing the error

Comment: I have just added it!

Comment: is Order class extending RealmObject ?

Comment: Yes, as stated above, Order is extending RealmObject. I also tried implementing RealmModel instead and adding the @RealmClass annotation, but with the same results.

Comment: Does disabling instant run help? What is your AS version?

Comment: I disabled it but it was not working, but finally, I got it resolved. We have two projects using Realm, so there it was the conflict. Thanks for all